# Access on view to not strongly typed data in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have following problem:
have to model classes (posts and users). Main view is strongly typed by posts (it shows list of them). But i want to enable voting on posts,but only when user is over 30 (field "age" in users). How get access (in most correct and good way) to fied "age"? And second q: how implement logic like this:

if age>30 show votebutton else dont (of course what is the best way for it).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you meant the **user of the posts** by **user** but if so, pass a ViewModel to your view. Something like below:

```
public class FooViewModel() {  

    public IEnumerable<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Then work on that on your view like below:

```
@if(Model.User.Age > 30) { 

    <div>
        Put your logic here...
    </div>
}
```

Also, when the data is being post, check this inside your controller action as well.